# Convert or cast types columns from tables to view with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2008 with SQL Server Management Studio 10 to create tables and views.

My problem is I want to create a view from several tables with a lots of columns but I'm limited by the size of the rows (8060 bytes per row).
Some columns have `varchar(255)` types, and according to the documentation this column cannot be out-of-row and to make it work I need to convert it to the `varchar(MAX)` value.
See this thread: [Strategies for bypassing the 8,060 byte limit on Row Length](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/strategies-for-bypassing-the-8060-byte-limit-on-row-length#post-1105726)

But I can't modify the original types.

So, how can I convert or cast with my view (if possible with the SSMS creation tool) the original types to `varchar(MAX)` values for example?

EDIT : Full statement

```
SELECT dbo.V_NUM1.rownum, dbo.V_NUM1.id, dbo.V_NUM1.PAR_N, CONVERT(nchar(MAX), dbo.V_NUM1.PAR_Objet) AS PAR_Objet, ...... , dbo.V_NUM2.PAR_gestion_site_theme, dbo.NUM3.COM_RCD_PAR_N 
FROM dbo.V_NUM1 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.V_NUM2 ON dbo.V_NUM1.PAR_ID = dbo.V_NUM2.PAR_ID 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.V_NUM3 ON dbo.V_NUM1.PAR_ID = dbo.V_NUM3.COM_RCD_PAR_N
```

Comment: So what's wrong with `CONVERT` here exactly..? What are you actually asking? *P.s. SQL Server 2008 has been unsupported for a year now, and you should be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible, if not already.*

Comment: `alter table`.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Larnu & Gordon Linoff : I've tried CONVERT(nchar(MAX), column_name) AS column_name but it fails "incorrect syntax near nchar". (column is type "nchar(255)"

Comment: @Larnu it's done.

Comment: Durp... Of course. There's no such thing as an `nchar(MAX)`. You want `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Also, I suggest changing those column references. [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

Comment: @Larnu There is no issues to convert nchar(255) to nvarchar(MAX) ? Thanks as well for the best practices, and for 3+ it's just SQL Server that generating that by default

Comment: `nchar` is just a fixed width string value. `nchar(MAX)` doesn't exist as that would mean that **every** row for that 1 column would take up 2GB of space. If you had just 500 rows you'd have almost 1TB of rows! Most of that, being empty space.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, indeed. But, I tried `RTRIM(nvarchar(MAX), ColumnName)) AS ColumnName` and I still have "Warning: The query processor could not produce a query plan from the optimizer because the total length of all the columns exceeds 8000 bytes." as an error, so my rows have still the same size